# How can I automatically answer a password prompt from an embedded item in an (X)HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, passwords, prompt

I wrote a web page that displays images from several servers on my network via simple img tags with appropriate href values.  The servers require authentication before they will send the images.

It works alright, except on first load the page presents the user with a series of password prompts (one for each server).  The user can select the "Remember my password" checkbox, and then subsequent refreshes of the page work without prompting, with correctly updated images.  That is, until someone closes out the browser, after which a new set of prompts awaits anyone who opens the page again.

All of the credentials needed are known beforehand, and I don't care if someone could read them in the page source, since this page is in a protected part of an internal intranet site.  Everyone with access to this page knows the passwords anyway.

The only browser we're allowed to use is IE 7, so I don't care about compatibility with other browsers at the moment.

Is there any way I can use JavaScript (or some other client-side code) to automatically answer those prompts so the user never sees them?

Thanks very much, in advance.

Comment: What server software is serving these pages?  It's possible to authentic the users server-side, but not client side AFAIK.

Comment: It's kind of an ugly hack.  This is an HTML page stored in a SharePoint site, then opened from a SharePoint document library.  I guess that means it's being served by IIS, but I don't have access to change the server software options, which is why I was asking about client-side code.

As for the other servers that the page is pulling images from, they are 3rd-party appliances with built-in webservers.  Not sure what platform, but I have very limited access to changing their configuration either.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the authentication in the URL:

```
<img src="http://paulfisher:tastybacon@internalwebs/path/to/image.png">
```

Where, of course, `paulfisher` is my username and my password is `tastybacon`.

Comment: That stopped working a couple of years ago.  It was deemed a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

No, javascript can't do this.  Here are a couple of options that I've used before to solve this problem:

1. Change the authentication on the other servers to be either anonymous or integrated.
2. Proxy in the images:  On the server serving the page, add another page that takes in the URL of the remote server.  This new page makes a webrequest to the other server and streams the image back.  The webrequest can plug in the correct credentials.
3. Depending on the servers' DNS names, it might be possible to share an authentication cookie across all of the servers.  Then you could set up some kind of module on all of the servers to allow the shared authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Sadly, my own page is all I really have control over in this scenario.  I can't change the behavior of any of the servers, which is why I'm relying on client-side code.

Thanks for the idea of the WebRequest, though.  I'll play with that and see what I can come up with.